# Перестановка элементов в произвольном массиве типа void

Tags: c, массивы

Имеется функция, которая принимает указатель `void *base` на произвольный массив.
Задача заключается в перестановке двух произвольных элементов между собой. Проблема в том, что этот массив может быть массивом целых чисел, а может быть массивом *указателей на строки*, например.
 Вопрос в том как правильно это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так, как это реализуется в стандартной функции `qsort`, например. То есть в функцию также надо передавать размер элемента массива. Адресную арифметику внутри функции реализовать в терминах байтов (т.е. через указатели типа `char *`). Например

```
void swap_ij(void *array, size_t size, size_t i, size_t j)
{
  unsigned char *ptr_i = (unsigned char *) array + i * size;
  unsigned char *ptr_j = (unsigned char *) array + j * size;

  // А далее обмениваем местами `size` байтов по указателям `ptr_i` и `ptr_j`
  // ...
}

int main(void)
{
  int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
  swap_ij(a, sizeof *a, 1, 3);

  const char *b[] = { "Vasya", "Petya", "Kolya" };
  swap_ij(b, sizeof *b, 0, 2);
}
```

При желании можно написать макрос-оболочку, который в некоторой степени будет эмулировать поведение С++ шаблонов

```
#define SWAP_IJ(a, i, j) swap_ij(a, sizeof *(a), i, j)
...
double c[] = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.8 };
SWAP_IJ(c, 2, 4);
```